# React Native changing device settings from inside your react-native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth, settings

I want to know if its possible to create a react-native app, which in ideal world will be able to change device name (with user permission of course) on both Android and iOS.

What I mean by this: user opens my app and will be asked a question if he allows app to change his device name. This would be the same as manually going through Settings => General => About => Name on the iPhone.

Why I need this: after changing device name, bluetooth name will be changed as well and I will be searching available devices around me by some specific names.

Comment: Definitely not in iOS.

Comment: Usually the practise is to redirect user from your mobile app to the specific settings screen to enable/toggle on the required permission/setting. Upon tapping "back" button, user will be navigated back to the App itself. For iOS, there's a small back button on top left screen when you navigated out from your app to settings screen.